# Is there a functionality to display the Average Time taken for a test to Run in TimeLine Tab in Jasmine allure reporter

Tags: jasmine, allure

In the Time Line tab , it displays the time taken to run the test. However there is a label called Default displayed. So what does that mean in a report .

Also is there any way of displaying the Average time taken to run the test as a time bar???[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported . Request is taken up.
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jasmine-plugin/issues/6